# specify that the given statements are correct or not

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(x)dx>\displaystyle\int_a^bg(x)dx$   ⇒

i) g(x) ≥ f(x) for x          ∈ [a,b]

ii) f(x)    ≥ g(x) for x ∈ [a,b]

i thought that we can take f(x)=1/x and and g(x)=sinx on (0,π) and get $\displaystyle\int_0^π(1/x)dx=∞>\displaystyle\int_0^π(sinx)dx$ = 2 , f(π/2) < g(π/2) for the 1st statement(i). But i am not sure about the accuracy of the 1st and 2nd statement. If they are false ,can you give me any counter-example?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of asking this question in the negative is "Do there exist the functions f and g so that the integral of f over some range is greater than g over that same range, but there also exists some point in that range where i) g(x) < f(x) or ii) f(x) < g(x)."

When asked from this perspective, it is fairly easy to construct counterexamples to both i) and ii). Personally, I think a point discontinuity on f and/or g would be the best way to go, but finding lines that fit the requirements would also be a fairly easy solution. Your proposed solution is unnecessarily complicated, but it actually provides a valid counterexample to both i) and ii)